# Django Channels unable to receive events during asyncio.sleep?

Tags: django, python-asyncio, django-channels, daphne

I am using `AsyncWebSocketConsumer` and I want to put consumer to sleep for 10 seconds while handling one specific event. So, on receiving that event I am calling `await asyncio.sleep(10)`. But problem with this is that it is blocking events to this consumer instance for next 10 seconds.

My question is that if I am using `AsyncConsumer`, shouldn't it continue sending future events even though I am on async sleep?

I have been going through the code of daphne server and found out following:

```
    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        # If we're muted, do nothing.
        if self.muted:
            logger.debug("Muting incoming frame on %s", self.client_addr)
            return
        logger.debug("WebSocket incoming frame on %s", self.client_addr)
        self.last_ping = time.time()
        if isBinary:
            self.application_queue.put_nowait(
                {"type": "websocket.receive", "bytes": payload}
            )
        else:
            self.application_queue.put_nowait(
                {"type": "websocket.receive", "text": payload.decode("utf8")}
            )
```

which means on receiving new event from frontend, it creates a new task and add it to async queue for consumer to consume. So, why sleep on one async task blocking other task? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

By the producer-consumer pattern, each consumer consumes the queue serially: get from queue > process > get from queue...
At the process phase for a given item (or "event") you are putting the consumer to sleep, so the process is not finished until the sleep is done. You can't consume the next item, that is why your consumer gets blocked.
You can make a new and **dedicated** consumer for that specific "event", that way the sleep will not block the processing of other events. See [asyncio.Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html?highlight=asyncio%20queue#asyncio.Queue), have your `AsyncWebSocketConsumer` own an async queue and fill that with [.put_nowait()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html?highlight=asyncio%20queue#asyncio.Queue.put_nowait) and have a daemon coroutine (a new consumer) consume that with [.get()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html?highlight=asyncio%20queue#asyncio.Queue.get), that new consumer can `await asyncio.sleep(10)` before getting the next item.
**Note** that queue should have a carefully defined `maxsize`, since it's items are popped every 10 seconds letting it grow without limits may consume much memory. When que queue is full, `put_nowait()` raises `asyncio.QueueFull`, catch it in `AsyncWebSocketConsumer` and just throw away the new item or find a way to tell the producer to slow down.

ps: I don't know how django channels works, I have never used it. (#twisted tag is not appropriate for this question).

Comment: I agree that via consumer/producer pattern it will consume it serially, but sometime to make thing efficient implementation do have more than one instance of consumer with shared queue. So, is there any way to make multiple consumers consuming same queue in Django channels. I added twisted tag, as Django channels in backend is using twisted for communication, so I am not sure whether this implementation is in daphne or in twisted.

Comment: You can have a shared queue but you need a item router/dispatcher that will send the "specific event" to its "specific consumer". My solution does not takes into account the internals of django channels as I don't know it, that's why `AsyncWebSocketConsumer` is the dispatcher here.

Comment: From what I searched, each "consumer" in django channels handles messages of a protocol, they are instantiated for each connection. So that `AsyncWebsocketConsumer` handles websocket messages. The dispatcher I was talking about is the routers in django channels, you registered your consumers in the `ProtocolTypeRouter`. So that "events" are actually websocket messages and you have a delay of 10 seconds when receiving a specific message. The only way I found to do that is by url routing, see [URLRouter].(https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/routing.html#urlrouter) @hardik24