# Django Channels sleep between group sends

Tags: python, django, channel

what i am trying to achieve is quite simple as you can read in the title but i can't get it to work "to sleep between two sends".
my code:

```
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
        str(self.game_link),
        {
            "type": "group_message",
            "text": json.dumps(answer_data),
        }
        )

        await asyncio.sleep(5)

        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
        str(self.game_link),
        {
            "type": "group_message",
            "text": json.dumps(data),
        }
        )
```

what happens here is that both send at the same time after sleep is done.

Answer (score 0):

After some search and read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62361242/django-channels-unable-to-receive-events-during-asyncio-sleep), I managed to get it work.

**Short Answer**

put `await asyncio.sleep(5)` inside `group_message` method

**Explain**

While awaiting `group_send`, the process is not send the message immediately, but instead send to the queue (for all members in the group).

Since this process is not finished, this channel is somewhat blocked and cannot consume the future message. The process has to sleep 5 seconds, await another `group_send`, and then finally consume the two messages in its own queue.

If you join the group from somewhere else (e.g. open another browser), you will receive the second message after 5s delay.

Putting `await asyncio.sleep(5)` inside `group_message` on the other hand, will only sleep when consuming the message.

NOTE add a filtering logical so that not all messages get sleep

```
async def group_message(self, data):
    if 'sleep' in data:
        await asyncio.sleep(data.pop('sleep'))
    await self.send(text_data=data['text'])
```

And in your message sender:

```
await self.channel_layer.group_send(
    str(self.game_link),
    {
        "type": "group_message",
        "text": json.dumps(data),
    }
)

# second message: sleep before send
await self.channel_layer.group_send(
    str(self.game_link),
    {
        "type": "group_message",
        "text": json.dumps(data),
        "sleep": 5
    }
)
```